# Can I import a C struct into Ghidra?

Tags: ghidra

Either by pasting from a text file or typing it out into a dialog box, which is still much faster than using Ghidra's Structure editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a file `foo.h` somewhere

Add your struct to that file.

File -> parse c source -> parse to program -> dismiss

Data type manager:
Data->choose Data Type and navigate to the header and apply your struct

contents of `dudu.h`

```
typedef unsigned char   undefined;

typedef unsigned int    dword;
typedef struct head_of_png_dude head_of_pnge_dud, *Phead_of_png_dude;

struct head_of_png_dude {
    dword pnghead;
    dword pngtail;
    dword pngfeet;
    dword yakk;
    dword bukk;
    dword luck;
};
```

parsed c source
[image: Ghidra Data Type Manager showing our new types]

The applied the data type:
[image: Ghidra Listing panel showing our struct applied]

Answer (score 2):

Using "Parse C Source" seems to **only** work if all other structs referenced by the parsed structs are also defined in such header files in correct order.

If you want to parse a struct that depends on types that have been added from another source (like plugins/scripts, PDB, or manually added), you could use a script.

This script allows you to do that: https://github.com/Katharsas/ghidra-struct-importer

(Disclaimer: I am the author of that repo)